# Cygwin, gcc and C_INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, c-preprocessor, include-path

First of all, I'm a complete Cygwin/Unix/gcc noob. (I've only used VC++)

I installed Cygwin and tried to compile some C programs.

Some header files (I'd say, "brabra.h" which is in /home/MyUsername/brabrabra/include) were needed so I did

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/MyUsername/brabrabra/include
```

and then tried to compile by

```
gcc -o program1 program1.c
```

but it said

```
brabra.h: No such file or directory
```

So I did

```
gcc -o program1 program1.c -v
```

and it said

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/../../../../lib/../include/w32api
End of search list.
```

So yea, it seems that the include directory I set by "export" command is not recognized by gcc.
What can I do?

Comment: What does `echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH` tell you after you did `export ...` as per you question?

Comment: As well what do you get for `ls $C_INCLUDE_PATH`?

Comment: "Is $C_INCLUDE_PATH not supported in the current version of Cygwin and GCC?" No it isn't. For this to work you need to be running GCC in a genuine unix/linux system. On Cygwin, do as @alk says.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do?

You could tell the compiler directly where to look for specific files.

This can be done by using the `-I` option.

```
gcc -I /home/MyUsername/brabrabra/include -o program1 program1.c
```

Note that this options need go *before* the source file which might need to look up the directory specified by `-I`, so the command shoud at least look like this:

```
gcc -o program1 -I /home/MyUsername/brabrabra/include program1.c
```

BTW, the `-L` option works the same, but for library files needed for linking.

Comment: Thanks. Is $C_INCLUDE_PATH not supported in the current version of Cygwin and GCC?